# Redhat Linux - SO file not found

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++, redhat

I am having trouble when running my compiled C++ code on linux. It worked fine on Ubuntu when I used the line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:../irrklang/lib/linux-gcc-64/
```

Before running my program. If I don't do this I receive an error:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libIrrKlang.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

On the version of Redhat I am using, it is a Uni PC and it has to run here. Running the export command above results in:

```
Bad : modifier in $ (.).
```

I've also tried:

```
ldconfig -l ../irrklang/lib/linux-gcc-64/libIrrKlang.so
```

But that did not work either. I'm not sure what else to try to get my program working.

EDIT:

I've just tried this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:"../irrklang/lib/linux-gcc-64/"
```

But this said that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is undefined

Comment: You should be able to make the export command work. It could be that you are using bourne shell. Try with bash.

Comment: The default shell was tcsh. The export command does work when used with bash. And I also need to run program in bash as well. I found out that I could set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in tsch with:

setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "../irrklang/lib/linux-gcc-64/"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user2672165 pointed me in the right direction. The shell was tcsh which required me to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "../irrklang/lib/linux-gcc-64/"
```

Another work around was to use bash for the export command and ./run